# I want to hide add new from my custom post in wordpress but if posts are empty then enable add new

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Here is my code:

```
function wpmudev_create_slider_text() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'sliderText',
    'singular_name' => 'Slider ',
    'add_new' => 'Add Text',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Text',
    'view_item' => 'View Text',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' => 'No Products Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Slider Text',
);

register_post_type('product', array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false,
    ),
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sliderText'),
        )
);


}

add_action('init', 'wpmudev_create_slider_text');
```

I want to hide add new if there is one active record if no active record(empty) then enable add new to insert one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should check number of active/publish post using `wp_count_posts( 'product' )->publish` and then using conditional statement you can disable add new functionality. Please check below code:

```
function disable_create_newpost() {
  global $wp_post_types;
  if(wp_count_posts( 'product' )->publish > 0){
     $wp_post_types['product']->cap->create_posts = 'do_not_allow';
  }
}
add_action('init','disable_create_newpost');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts